# Always keep some empty space or lines below cursor position in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vim, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VsVim extension with Visual Studio 2015. Is there a way to always have empty space or lines of code (if present) below the current editor cursor position in Visual Studio. I have seen a setting in vim that gives this feature. Is something like that available in Visual Studio as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. As per https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/Settings-Reference, I created a _vimrc file in %USERPROFILE% location with a setting as set scrolloff=3. This works for VsVIM. I think something like that might exist for Visual Studio as well (without VsVIM)